# Convert string to TimeSpan doesn't work

Tags: timespan, managed-c++

i'm trying to convert a string into timeSpan but i can't seem to do it.

i'm using c++ managed code:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan;
if (TimeSpan::TryParse("01.55", timeSpan))
{  
  int minute = timeSpan.Minutes;
  int hours= timeSpan.Hours;
  //do some work here
}
```

the TryParse is returning flase.
what am i doing wrong ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The time format is wrong, see [MSDN TimeSpan::TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1).

The format should be: `[ws][-]{ d | d.hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] | hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]`

Or short for your example `1:55` instead of `1.55`. This is format for **1 hour** and  **55 minutes**. Your notation is for `days.hours`, which is also wrong as day has only 24 hours so TimeSpan allows max value of 23. Your string still needs `:0:0` so it forms `dd.hh:mm:ss` to be successfully parsed.

Comment: As the parser is not prone to `.` or `:` errors at `d(./:)hh`, you can just [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) all `.` to `:` and then parse it. I think that syntax is simple enough so I won't explain it here. If not, there is simple example on link which shows you all you need to know.

Comment: so i need to re-format the string and concat it ":0:0" so this will work ?

Comment: Just use `yourXMLString = yourXMLString->Replace('.',':');` and then use `TimeSpan::TryParse(yourXMLString,timeSpan)`. Be sure not to replace in whole xml file as you could replace any content you do not wish to modify.

Comment: thx , replacing it worked. just can't figure one thing out. when i'm using "02:55" how does TimeSpan::TryParse don't ""think" that the "02" is the number of days?

Comment: Because the guys who were programming that were smart enough think of that before and program it so it defaults to `hh:mm` (if you provide 2 numbers, separated by `:`). The default format for days is `d.hh:mm` but if you provide 4 numbers, all separated with `:`, it knows that those are `dd:hh:mm:ss`. Although, when providing ms, you must separate days with `.` and the same with ms, like this `dd.hh:mm:ss.ms` or it won't work. If that helped you, I'd appreciate a accepted question :)